# Prove the rational $\mathbb{Q}$ is not neighbourhood of any of its points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

The rational $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a neighbourhood of any its points.

My second attempt: prove its negation **the rationals is the neighbourhood of some of its points** is false. Let $\frac{m}{n},\frac{p}{q}$ in open interval $I$ with $\frac{m}{n}<\frac{p}{q}$. we always be able to find a non-rational $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q})$ in the interval, so such interval is not the susbet of $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, my first attempt was not involving two rational, just beginning with $\left(\frac{p}{q}-\epsilon,\frac{p}{q}+\epsilon\right)$ and stuck. Looking for how to build another irrational involving $\epsilon$ and one rational only in this set $\left(\frac{p}{q}-\epsilon,\frac{p}{q}+\epsilon\right)$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Find a rational $\,r \in (0,\epsilon)\,$, then find an irrational in $\,(p/q-r, \,p/q+r) \subseteq (p/q-\epsilon, \,p/q+\epsilon)\,$.

Comment: You must state in the question what the including set is. One would suppose this is $\Bbb R$, but…

Comment: @Lubin Thank you for your reply. I am not sure which one you are talking about

Comment: To speak of a neighborhood of a point $P$, you must say which space is the space that $P$ lies in. Here, I’m sure that your including space is $\Bbb R$; but if you ask for a neighborhood of a point $P$ in the space $\Bbb Q$, your answer will be totally different.

Comment: As Lubin pointed out, it depents on your ambient space. If you're talking about $\mathbb{R}$, its easy to construct counterexamples. Neighborhoods are dependent on the underlying topology